# Addind an Optional.absent() element to a collection in Guava

Tags: java, guava

I can't find the trick here: I want a function to return a list of optional objects in order to mean that my list does contain this many elements but that some of them are not valid.

```
public Optional<String> getMyObjects() {
  List<Optional<String>> result = Lists.newArrayListWithCapacity(2);

  result.add(Optional.of("This value is valid"));
  result.add(Optional.absent()); // Compiler error

  return result;
}
```

This does not compile:

```
The method add(Optional<String>) in the type List<Optional<String>> is not 
applicable for the arguments (Optional<Object>)
```

How would you put it? I have tried casting without success

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
result.add(Optional.<String>absent());
```

Read more [about parametrized methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html#What%20is%20a%20parameterized%20%28or%20generic%29%20method?) and [explicit type argument specification](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20explicit%20type%20argument%20specification?) in great yet unofficial Java Generics FAQ.

Comment: Thanks all. Marked the first answer as correct and upvoted the others.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
result.add(Optional.<String>absent())
```

to force the generic type.

Or, to let the compiler infer it:

```
Optional<String> o = Optional.absent();
result.add(o);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
result.add(Optional.<String> absent());
```

The [absent()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#absent%28%29) method is parametrized.